# Get a string in a line with a string pattern (CMD) - Windows Batch

Tags: string, windows, cmd, command-prompt, findstr

I'm using windows command prompt (cmd).
I have this file "myfile.txt" and i want to **get the string in each line that match my pattern**.
For instance, if i have this in "myfile.txt":

`The file alpha_123.txt has been created`
`The file gama_234.txt has been created`
`The new file alpha_789.txt has been created`

And if I search for "alpha", the result should be this: 
`alpha_123.txt`
`alpha_789.txt`

For now i have this code:
`findstr /c "alpha" myfile.txt` but it returns the full line, but i just want the specific string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll probably have to write a small program.  [You could try AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) which is a relatively easy to learn text/data extraction and manipulation program.

Comment: AWK is linux based right? 
I'm working with windows batch

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in the correct directory, something like this should work.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %G in ('findstr "alpha" MyFile.txt') do @echo %G
```

Or something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %G in ('findstr /r "\<alpha_.*txt" MyFile.txt') do @echo %G
```

Comment: It might not be on token 3.

Comment: Quite a handy little detail to know from the get go...

Answer (score 0):

This can be used at a `cmd` `command-prompt` on `windows`.

```
powershell -nop -c ((sls 'alpha.*?\s' myfile.txt).Matches.Value).Trim()
```

If placed into a `cmd` `batch-file`, aliases should not be used.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    ((Select-String -Pattern 'alpha.*?\s' -Path 'myfile.txt').Matches.Value).Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite straight forward: get each line, write each word (token) and filter for the desired string:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "search=alpha"

for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    echo %%b|find "%search%"
  )
)
```